# Possessive 's' when having multiple owners - Was it Russell's and Whitehead's book?

Tags: possessives

Russell and Whitehead jointly published the famous book Principia Mathematica.

Should we write "in  Russell and Whitehead's  Principia Mathematica", or rather "in  Russell's and Whitehead's  Principia Mathematica".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apostrophe s only goes after "Whitehead"

> This is Russell and Whitehead's book.

This is analysed as apostrophe s being a "clitic" and not a true marker of genitive case.  Just as you don't say "a book of Russell and of Whitehead" (you say "the book of Russell and Whitehead"), you don't repeat the "apostrophe s".